# C++ Vector of structs, read access violation

Tags: c++, visual-c++

**Edit: For loop didn't have a ending condition. Newbie mistakes.**

I'm doing a school assignment for school, using MS VS, which has very specific
requirements. We're reading shape names and dimensions from a txt file, creating a struct for each shape with only the dimensions as members, and using a supporting function to calculate area/volume and output the results. Have to have 4 Loops:

- The First will parse a txt file line by line,
  check the type of shape, create a dynamic object and put it into a
  generic bag.
- The Second will process the bag and output the type of shape,
  dimensions, and calculations to console.
- The Third will do the same but output to another txt file.
- The Last loop will delete all dynamic objects.

My program with only the code for squares:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

  string line, str;
  double d1, d2, d3;
  map < string, int > shapes;
  vector<void*> myBag;
  vector<char> myBagType;

  shapes.insert(pair<string, int>("SQUARE", 1));

  ifstream shapesin("TextFile1.txt");
  ofstream shapesout("TextFile2.txt");

  if (!shapesin || !shapesout)
  {
    cout << "Unable to open file\n";
  }

  while (getline(shapesin, line)) 
  {
    d1 = d2 = d3 = 0;
    vector<string> token = parseString(line);

    if (token.size() >= 1) 
    {
      str = token[0];
      switch (shapes[str])
      {
      case 1: //Square
      {
        Square* s = new Square;
        myBag.push_back(s);
        myBagType.push_back('S');
        if (token.size() < 2) 
        {
          s->side = 0;
          break;
        }
        else
        {
          str = token[1];
          d1 = atof(str.c_str());
          s->side = d1;
        }
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  for (unsigned int i = 0; myBag.size(); i++)
  {
    if (myBagType[i] == 'S')
    {
      Square* aSquare = reinterpret_cast<Square*>(myBag[i]);
      Square& bSquare = *aSquare;
      outputSquare(cout, bSquare);
    }
  }

  for (unsigned int i = 0; myBag.size(); i++)
  {
    if (myBagType[i] == 'S')
    {
      Square* aSquare = reinterpret_cast<Square*>(myBag[i]);
      Square& bSquare = *aSquare;
      outputSquare(shapesout, bSquare);
    }
  }

  for (unsigned int i = 0; myBag.size(); i++)
  {
    if (myBagType[i] == 'S')
    {
      Square* aSquare = reinterpret_cast<Square*>(myBag[i]);
      delete aSquare;
    }
  }

  shapesin.close();
  shapesout.close();
  }
}

vector<string> parseString(string str)
{
  stringstream s(str);
  istream_iterator<string> begin(s), end;
  return vector<string>(begin, end);
}

void outputSquare(ostream& shapesout, const Square& x)
{
  double perim, area;
  perim = (x.side * 4); //exception thrown here
  area = (x.side * x.side);

  shapesout << "SQUARE " << "side=" << x.side;
  shapesout.setf(ios::fixed);
  shapesout.precision(2);
  shapesout << " area=" << area << " perimeter=" << perim << endl;
  shapesout.unsetf(ios::fixed);
  shapesout.precision(6);
}
```

Txt file input is:

SQUARE 14.5 344
SQUARE
RECTANGLE 14.5    4.65
DIMENSIONS
CIRCLE 14.5

BOX x 2 9

CUBE 13
BOX 1 2 3
CYLINDER 2.3 4 56
CANDY

SPHERE 2.4
CYLINDER 1.23
CYLINDER 50 1.23
TRIANGLE 1.2 3.2
PRISM 2.199 5

EOF

I know I have a problem with the way I'm accessing the struct member `x.side` but every other way I've tried won't compile, where as this will at least output the first line. I've read other, similar, questions but couldn't find one quite like this. I would really appreciate some assistance.

Comment: Use a debugger to trace your program execution step by step, or just run until it crashes. By examining its state at the time of the crash you might be able to figure out when it went wrong.

Comment: Hint: `for (unsigned int i = 0; myBag.size(); i++)` do you see something amiss here?

Comment: @n. 'pronouns' m. So I'm getting "An invalid parameter was passed" at `if (myBagType[i] == 'S')` for some reason. Should `for (unsigned int i = 0; myBag.size(); i++)` be `for (unsigned int i = 0; myBagType.size(); i++)` ?

Comment: The condition `myBag.size()` is always true. The loop `for (unsigned int i = 0; myBag.size(); i++)` does not terminate, until eventually `i` becomes too large and the program exhibits undefined behavior by way of accessing an index out of bounds.

Comment: That's embarrassing, no wonder. Thanks so much folks.

Comment: Will do, have to wait 2 days to accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for (unsigned int i = 0; myBag.size(); i++)`

No terminating condition

`for (unsigned int i = 0; i < myBag.size(); i++)`

Fixed